# I got corrected 上手し for 上手なので, but why?

Tags: grammar, particles

I was writing a composition in Japanese, and since I wanted to give reasons I wrote the following:

僕は日本語の会話がまだできないし、友達は英語が上手**し**、日本語を少ししか練習しませんでした。

However, I got corrected like this:

僕は日本語の会話がまだできないし、友達は英語が上手**なので**、日本語を少ししか練習しませんでした。

I don't understand why I can't use し or why it's better ので in this context. Can anyone explain me the reason?

Comment: I think it should be 友達 **も** 英語が上手だし to be a bit more natural. (Or should that be 友達は英語も ?)

Answer (score 5):

> 友達は英語が上手**し**、

I'm afraid 「[上手]{じょうず}し」/「[上手]{うま}し」 is incorrect.

I think you could use ～し, ～ので, or ～から here. You could say like this, using the na-adjective [上手]{じょうず}な:

> [上手]{じょうず}**だ**し、
>   上手なので、
>   上手だから、

or, using the i-adjective [上手]{うま}い:

> [上手]{うま}**い**し、
>   上手いので、
>   上手いから、

「～し」 and 「～から」 would sound more casual than 「～ので」.

Answer (score 3):

上手し is wrong. It must be 上手だし.

According to "A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar", page 396, na-adjectives and nouns must be followed by だし (or だったし if it is the past tense).

Examples:
先生だし (noun + だし)
綺麗だし (na-adjective + だし)

Grammatically that is the only mistake.

You teacher used ので probably just to make it clear that it implies a reason or cause.
し, on the other hand, does not imply reason or cause, it is just an emphatic "and".

Comment: `し does not imply reason or cause,  it is just an emphatic "and"` <- But [デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/92431/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%97/) says し can indicate 原因・理由: "し 1⃣［接助］２ 前に挙げた事柄を**原因・理由**として下の事柄に続ける意を表す。**から。ので。** 「身体はじょうぶですし、もっと働けます」「家も近いんだし、たまには寄れよ」"

Comment: Basically ので indicates *the* reason, し indicates *a* reason (non-exhaustive). Since all of these し reasons participate in the causality, you get the "and" meaning.